# Rescanning a text file in a method

Tags: java

I have a method that scans a text file and sets array elements and values to what I need them to be at.

```
public SoftDrinkInventory(Scanner inventoryFile) {


    initializeString(names);
       initializeString(ids);
       initializeInt(startingInventory);
       initializeInt(finalInventory);
       initializeInt(transactionCounts);

       while (inventoryFile.hasNext()){
           names[i] = inventoryFile.next();
           ids[i] = inventoryFile.next();
           startingInventory[i] = inventoryFile.nextInt();
           i++;
       }
    }

    public void processTransactions(Scanner transFile){ 

           while (transFile.hasNext()){      
               String key = transFile.next();
               int value = transFile.nextInt();
               for(i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
                   finalInventory[i] = startingInventory[i];
                   if(ids[i].equals(key)){
                       finalInventory[i] += value;
                   }
               }
           }


    }
```

The problem I am having is in the `processTransactions` method. I want run the while loop for each element in ids[]. How would I do that?

Comment: Rght now your while loop in processTransactions iterates until the file has text. What do you want to change?

Comment: It is running properly to the point it reads the whole text file has stopped, but I want it to run again from the beginning of the text file as many times as the number of ids array elements i have.

Comment: Let's say ids goes up to [6]. i want my while loop to run and scan the entire text file 6 times, or whatever i change my ids array to.

Comment: @ShanSolo Please show us the code where you create the `new Scanner()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to do this with just a `Scanner`. A `Scanner` has no means to seek back to the beginning of its input source.

You may wish to pass around the `InputStream` instead and create the `Scanner` as needed; you can `reset()` the `InputStream` (although not all `InputStream`s support that, but `FileInputStream` usually does) then create a new `Scanner` on it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by putting a scanner into an input stream.. could you give me an example?

Comment: @ShanSolo Please show us the code where you create the `new Scanner()`. Niks Tyagi's answer is also good and is essentially the same as mine, but you seem to be confused about the same thing in both; so we need to see where the `Scanner` comes from to help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead to pass `Scanner` object in method processTransactions,pass File path:

```
public void processTransactions(String filepath){ 

     for (String string : id) {    // Assume id is array of String
              Scanner transFile = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
                while (transFile.hasNext()){      
                       String key = transFile.next();
                       int value = transFile.nextInt();
                       for(i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
                           finalInventory[i] = startingInventory[i];
                           if(ids[i].equals(key)){
                               finalInventory[i] += value;
                           }
                       }
                   }    
                }

            }
```

Comment: @Shan Solo added answer,check and let me knw

Comment: I'm not sure where you got filepath from. i do not know where to declare what filepath is.

Comment: How are you initialising the Scanner object with is pass to this method, offcource like Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file path ")).So now pass the file path as String to this method

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not sure what you mean. But just a note, I am still learning basic java, nothing too complicated yet.

Comment: Can you tell me how you initialise the transFile object ??